# getting the output of a grep command in a loop

Tags: bash, function, shell, grep

I have a shell script that includes this search:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -iPho "barh(li|mar|ag)" {}  \;
```

I want to capture each string the grep command finds and send it a function I will create named "parser"

```
parser(){ 
# do stuff with each single grep result found
}
```

how can that be done?
is this right?

```
find . -type f -exec grep -iPho "barh(li|mar|ag)" {parser $1}  \;
```

I do not want to output the entire find command result to the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only shell can execute a function. You need to use `bash -c` in your `find` in order to execute it. That is also the reason you need to export your function, so that the new process sees it.

```
parser() { 
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        echo "Processing line: $line"
    done <<< "$1"
}

export -f parser
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'parser "$(grep -iPho "barh(li|mar|ag)" "$1")"' -- {} \;
```

The code above will send all occurrences from file1, then file2 etc to your function to process. It **will not** send each line one by one and therefore you need to loop over the lines in your function. If there is no occurrence of your regex in a file, it will **still** call your function with an empty input!

That might not be the best solution for you so let's try to add the loop inside the `bash -c` statement and **really** process the lines one by one:

```
parser() { 
    echo "Processing line: $1"
}

export -f parser
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'grep -iPho "barh(li|mar|ag)" "$@" | while IFS= read -r line; do parser "$line"; done' -- {} +
```

---

**EDIT:** Very nice and simple solution not using `bash -c` suggested by @gniourf_gniourf:

```
parser() { 
   echo "Processing line: $1"
}

find . -type f -exec grep -iPho "barh(li|mar|ag)" {} + | while IFS= read -r line; do parser "$line"; done
```

This approach works fine and it **will** process each line one by one. You also **do not** need to export your function with this approach. But you have to care for some things that might surprise you.

Each command in a pipeline is executed in its own subshell, and any variable assignment in your `parser` function or your `while` in general will be lost after returning from that very subshell. If you are writing a script, simple `shopt -s lastpipe` will suffice and run the last pipe command in the current shell environment. Or you can use process substitution:

```
parser() {
   echo "Processing line: $1"
}

while IFS= read -r line; do 
   parser "$line"; 
done < <(find . -type f -exec grep -iPho "barh(li|mar|ag)" {} +)
```

Note that in the previous `bash -c` examples, you will experience the same behavior and your variable assignments will be lost as well.

Comment: Re. the `while read` loop: if that's what OP wants, then `find ... -exec grep ... {} + | while read line; do parser "$line"; done` is a good suggestion.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Thanks for the suggestion! I added it to the answer, if you do not mind.

Comment: this worked for me:
`find . -type f -exec grep -iPho "barh(li|mar|ag)" {} \; | while IFS= read -r line; do parser "$line"; done`
...
notice the `\;` instead of the '+'...
marked as answer. thanks.

Comment: @john_black `{} +` is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You need to export your function.

You also need to call bash to execute the function.

```
parser() {
  echo "GOT: $1"
}
export -f parser

find Projects/ -type f -name '*rb' -exec bash -c 'parser "$0"' {} \;
```

Comment: note that i'm talking about the "grep" command, not just the "find".
I tried this:
`find . -type f -exec grep -iPho "barh(li|mar|ag)"  -exec bash -c 'parser "$0"' {}  \;`

and it gave me an error

Comment: Sure. But the 2 bits missing are the `bash -c` and the `export` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use sed ,this is more powerful tool to do text processing.
for example i want to add string "myparse" after the line that end as "ha",i can do this like

```
# echo "haha" > text1
# echo "hehe" > text2
# echo "heha" > text3
# find . -type f -exec sed '/ha$/s/ha$/ha myparse/' {} \;
haha myparse
heha myparse
hehe
```

if you really want to replace the file ,not just print to stdout,you can do this like

```
# find . -type f -exec sed -i '/ha$/s/ha$/ha myparse/' {} \;
```